# How to display a sequence of widgets on the same row?

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter, and I was wondering if I can display a sequence of widgets on the same row instead of placing them one below the other one in a column.

I'm currently using frames to place my components, however if I have several widgets (buttons) in a frame, I would prefer to directly place the button as I want, instead of creating additional subframes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use geometry managers to lay out widgets within a container. Tkinter's geometry managers are [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

**grid** allows you to lay out your widgets in rows and columns. **pack** allows you to lay out your widgets along sides of a box (and great for making single horizontal or vertical columns). **place** lets you use absolute and relative positioning. In practice, place is used very infrequently.

In your case, you want to create a horizontal row of buttons which is typically done by creating a frame that represents the row, and then using pack to place the widgets side by side. Don't be afraid of using subframes for layout -- that is exactly what they are for.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        # this will be the container for a row of buttons
        # a background color has been added just to make
        # it stand out.
        container = tk.Frame(self.root, background="#ffd3d3")

        # these are the buttons. If you want, you can make these
        # children of the container and avoid the use of "in_" 
        # in the pack command, but I find it easier to maintain
        # code by keeping my widget hierarchy shallow.
        b1 = tk.Button(text="Button 1")
        b2 = tk.Button(text="Button 2")
        b3 = tk.Button(text="Button 3")

        # pack the buttons in the container. Since the buttons
        # are children of the root we need to use the in_ parameter.
        b1.pack(in_=container, side="left")
        b2.pack(in_=container, side="left")
        b3.pack(in_=container, side="left")

        # finally, pack the container in the root window
        container.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. One more thing, how can I specify the spacing between the components ? (For example, add some left marging before each button)

Comment: @Patrick: use options like "padx" and "pady" in the pack command.